# gwt : drag n drop tree

Tags: gwt, drag-and-drop, tree, components

I need a tree drag n drop component...but this component does not appear in gwt samples...

I do not understand if Vaadin, under LGPL licence mean that I will need to pay for my 'commercial' application ?

Can I develop my own drag n drop tree component in GWT (is it complex) ?

Tkx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In GWT 2.4 there will be drag and drop support I think. With this new feature you can add drag and drop support to almost every widget. Right now 2.4 is in bèta. At Google I/O there was a sessions about GWT and drag and drop. You can watch it here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEkR1ox_K10

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gwt-dnd](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/) to implement drag-and-drop in ordinary gwt Tree. This should be easy, all you need is provided by gwt-dnd and gwt Tree, just wire things together and add some logic (what can be dragged, how should it look, where can it be dropped and what happens then and so on).

Comment: but I am desapointed to not see the example I need in gwt-dnd...it would be a tree that I can re-organize the hierarchie with drag n drop...I think that the new feature in GWT 4 would have exactly what I have, and I will be able to use it in the right new way...so I will wait for it. Tkx a lot, ++